# IIS rewrite rules not working as expected

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have researched this item thoroughly and am, in my opinion, doing the right thing. However, it's not working so my opinion must be wrong!

I have a website in which all the content is in wwwroot or other folders.
I am trying to get HTML5 URLs to work. 
The website is presented with 5 URL types.

1. An empty URL.
2. A URL intended for a physical file, e.g., a css, html or js file
3. A URL /api/... to access Resources
4. A URL /oauth/token for authentication
5. An HTML5 type url, say /aboutus

I have the following rewrite rules in web.config

```
    <rule name="index.html as document root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/wwwroot/index.html" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="static dist files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}wwwroot\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/wwwroot/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="api call" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/api/" />
      <action type="None"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="authorization call" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/oauth/token$" />
      <action type="None"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="reroute html5 to index.html" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.+$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/wwwroot/index.html" />
    </rule>
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. The documentation I can find for "stopProcessing" is imprecise but I am assuming that it means if the rule is matched, do not process any more rules.

What is happening is that no calls to the API or for authentication are handled correctly - by Debugging the API is not called and instead it appears to be rewritten to wwwroot/index.html.

I am sure I am doing something really simple wrong, but I have tried everything I can think of that makes sense.

Any help appreciated.

The server is using OWIN with JWT and the frontent is AngularJS. I am using VS2015 Community for development.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <!-- This is the root document for the Angular app -->
    <add value="wwwroot/index.html" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>

<rewrite>
  <rules>

    <rule name="static dist files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}wwwroot\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/wwwroot/{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <!-- Allows "api/" prefixed URLs to still hit Web API controllers 
                         as defined in WebApiConfig -->
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="api/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <!-- Allow "oauth/token" to do autnentication -->
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="oauth/token" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

After much trial and error, I finally got it to work and now I have it working it's all obvious.

The defaultDocument takes care of case 1 in the original question.
The "static dist files" rule handles case 2.
The "Main Rule" takes care of case 5 making sure to leave cases 3 and 4 untouched.